# Scraping three diffrent texts in three same html codes

Tags: python, excel, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, openpyxl

In this code I just want to scrape the movies' duration data but it also scrapes the movies' release dates too!!! I post the HTML codes as well to show you the problem better.

```py
import openpyxl as opx
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

wb = opx.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "Movies"

header_row = ["Name", "Date", "Rate", "duration"]
ws.append(header_row)

url = "https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250"
header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
html_content = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
movies = soup.find_all(
    "li", class_="ipc-metadata-list-summary-item sc-bca49391-0 eypSaE cli-parent")


for movie in movies:
    name = movie.find("h3", class_="ipc-title__text").text.strip()
    date = movie.find(
        "span", class_="sc-14dd939d-6 kHVqMR cli-title-metadata-item")
    rate = movie.find(
        "span", class_="ipc-rating-star ipc-rating-star--base ipc-rating-star--imdb ratingGroup--imdb-rating")

    print(duration.text)

# wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. One is using `find_all` which returns list of matches.

```
...
duration = movie.find_all('span', class_='sc-14dd939d-6 kHVqMR cli-title-metadata-item')[1]
...
```

Next one is using `select` or `select_one`.

```
duration = movie.select_one('span.sc-14dd939d-6.kHVqMR.cli-title-metadata-item:nth-child(2)')
```

`select` and `select_one` uses CSS Selectors. In above code, it searches for `2nd` `span` inside `movie` element that has classes including `sc-14dd939d-6`, `kHVqMR` and `cli-title-metadata-item`. Note that since it uses css, it selects any span containing those three classes even if there are more classes.

To check if second element is present before taking text:

```
duration = duration.text.strip() if duration else '-'
```

You can check more in [BeautifulSoup Docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). It is really well-written with numerous examples.